# Compute the groups $\mathrm{Tor}_n^R(k,k)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> I want to compute the groups $\mathrm{Tor}_n^R(k,k)$ where $R$ is the completion of the local ring of the curve $y^2-x^3$ at the point $y = x = 0$ and $k = R/(x,y)$.

Could anyone help me to work through this question? I've been stuck on this problem for a long time and have no idea how to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ring $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ embeds in $k[t]$ via $x\mapsto t^2$ and $y\mapsto t^3$. The image is the polynomials in $t^2$ and $t^3$. Completing
at the origin gives $R$ is the ring of formal power series
of the form $a_0+a_2t^2+a_3 t^3+a_4t^4+\cdots$.

Now create a free resolution of $k$. Naturally we map $R$ to $k$ by
$1\mapsto 1$. The kernel is $I=(t^2,t^3)$. Now we map $R^2$ to $I$
by $(f,g)\mapsto t^2f+t^3g$. The kernel is $K=\{(th,-h):h=a_2t^2+a_3t^3+\cdots\}$. This is isomorphic to $I$ as an $R$-module. The resolution
becomes periodic.

So we get a free resolution of $k$ with $F_0=R$ and $F_n=R^2$
for $n\ge1$. The general differential can be taken to be
$(f,g)\to (t^3 f+t^4g,-t^2f-t^3g)$ while that from $F_1$ to $F_0$
is $(f,g)\to t^2 f+t^3g$. We need to tensor with $k$ to get the
complex which yield the Tor groups. I reckon all the maps in this
complex are zero, so $\text{Tor}_0^R(k,k)=k$ and $\text{Tor}_n^R(k,k)=k^2$
for $n>0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A question I have is how did you conclude that $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ is the local ring of the curve $y^2-x^3$ at the origin? I've read the definitions of Eisenbud, but I wasn't able to conclude that. Thanks!

Comment: $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)\cong k[t^2,t^3]$ is not a local ring, but completing it at the maximal ideal yields the **power series ring** as described.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit more on how did you choose the differential $(f,g) \rightarrow (t^3f+t^4g,-t^2f-t^3g)$ and how you get the Tor groups from the complex tensored with $k$? Thanks!!

Comment: @user110320 This follows the paradigm of choosing the minimal free resolution with a local ring. Then the differentials when tensored with $k$ become zero.

Comment: Then, are you choosing the $t^3, t^4, -t^2$ and $-t^3$ coefficients to send the elements from $F_n$ to the minimal set of generators of $F_{n-1}$?
 Also, does the choice of coefficients have anything to do with the fact that the kernel $K = \{(th,-h) : h = a_2t^2 +a_3t^3 + ...\}$?

Comment: @user110320 All I have done is identify some obvious generators of the kernel, and then mapped generators of a free module to them.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help!! One final thing would be, how do you know the differential maps would go to zero under the application of the tensor functor and how do you know that $\ker(\phi_i\otimes k)/Im(\phi_{i+1} \otimes k) = k^2$ for $i\geq 1$  where $\phi_i$ is the map from $F_i \rightarrow F_{i-1}$? Thanks again!

Comment: @user110320 You can just sit down and work all these details out...